# Yarn is unable to upgrade, why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yarnpkg

```
error An unexpected error occurred: "EACCES: permission denied, unlink '/home/ubuntu/environment/sample_app/node_modules/.bin/acorn'".
```

this is what the file looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
'use strict';

require('../dist/bin.js');
```

I wasn't having a problem like this before, what's going on?

**UPDATE** here's the full error log:

```
yarn upgrade v1.22.4
[1/4] Resolving packages...
warning @rails/webpacker > node-sass > request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
warning @rails/webpacker > node-sass > node-gyp > request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
warning @rails/webpacker > webpack > watchpack > watchpack-chokidar2 > chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
warning @rails/webpacker > webpack > watchpack > watchpack-chokidar2 > chokidar > fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
warning @rails/webpacker > webpack > micromatch > snapdragon > source-map-resolve > resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
warning @rails/webpacker > webpack > micromatch > snapdragon > source-map-resolve > urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
warning popper.js@1.16.1: You can find the new Popper v2 at @popperjs/core, this package is dedicated to the legacy v1
warning webpack-dev-server > chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
[2/4] Fetching packages...
info fsevents@2.1.3: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@2.1.3" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info fsevents@1.2.13: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@1.2.13" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
warning " > webpack-dev-server@3.11.0" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0".
warning "webpack-dev-server > webpack-dev-middleware@3.7.2" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^4.0.0".
error An unexpected error occurred: "EACCES: permission denied, unlink '/home/ubuntu/environment/sample_app/node_modules/.bin/acorn'".
info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "/home/ubuntu/environment/sample_app/yarn-error.log".
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/upgrade for documentation about this command.
```

**UPDATE**
the problem is still persisting, no matter what I do or type in. I seem to not have 'permissions' to do anything, and I don't understand why considering I could do this before. After I input the **$ yarn install --check-files** command, I receive this:

```
yarn install v1.22.4
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
info fsevents@2.1.3: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@2.1.3" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info fsevents@1.2.13: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@1.2.13" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
warning " > webpack-dev-server@3.11.0" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0".
warning "webpack-dev-server > webpack-dev-middleware@3.7.2" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^4.0.0".
error An unexpected error occurred: "EACCES: permission denied, unlink '/home/ubuntu/environment/sample_app/node_modules/.bin/acorn'".
info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "/home/ubuntu/environment/sample_app/yarn-error.log".
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
```

Looking at my acorn file, this is what it looks like:|

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
'use strict';

require('../dist/bin.js');
```

I don't know what to do.

Comment: Have you tried a fresh install by first deleting the existing node_modules? I had a similar issue caused by mounting a volume to a container with an existing node_modules, removing node_modules before mounting the volume fixed my scenario.

Comment: I was just considering this, based on previous similar questions. This sounds silly, but could you perhaps walk me through? How do I do that?

Comment: Using a terminal, you can run `rm -rf node_modules` to delete your node_modules directory. The next time you run `yarn install` it will perform a fresh install.

In your case, you'd run `cd /home/ubuntu/environment/sample_app` followed by the command above.

Comment: So I just tried this and interesting to note is that on all the files, it says Permission Denied. It seems I don't have permission?

`rm: cannot remove 'node_modules/node-sass/node_modules/.bin/in-publish': Permission denied`

Comment: What's your environment? Is this a local machine?

Comment: again apologies if I'm slow with the terminology; this is all new to me but ubuntu? Yes I'm using my own computer but I'm using the cloud9 console ( from aws )